# HIVE REMOVE COLUMNS FROM EXTERNAL PARTITIONED TABLE

Tags: hive

I need to Remove a column from an external partitioned table in hive. How can we do it.

Can someone please provide the command ASAP.

Thanks

Comment: You are member since more than 2 years, maybe you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and next improve your question

Answer (score 1):

You ca use ALTER command

example usage:
ALTER TABLE name DROP [COLUMN] column_name

Whenever you specify partitions in an ALTER TABLE statement, through the PARTITION (partition_spec) clause, you must include all the partitioning columns in the specification.

Most of the ALTER TABLE operations work the same for internal tables as for external tables (with data files located in arbitrary locations). The exception is renaming a table; for an external table, the underlying data directory is not renamed or moved.

Refer cloudera/ apache hive docs link for more info

Comment: Thanks Anil for suggesting